# ActiveRecords joins - order between belongs_to and has many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord

This seems like a simple question but I've looked for a while and could not find an answer...

I have three models:

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :classes
end

class Classe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teachers
  belongs_to :rooms
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :classes
end
```

From a teacher name, I would like to get all his classes and the room associated with each of those classes. I have tried a combinations of queries with `joins` and `includes` but could not get one right...

Also, what is the reason why `Teacher.joins(:classes)` works but not `Classe.joins(:teachers)` ?

Comment: I think you have a typo in there: it should be `belongs_to :teacher` (singular), not `teachers`. Also, I'm surprised that Rails correctly singularizes 'Classes' to 'Classe'. Shouldn't that be 'Class'?

Comment: In which context would you like to get a teachers' classes and associated rooms, i.e. how/where would you like to use them? I'm asking because you don't really have to use `includes` here - that's just an optional performance optimisation thing, and `joins` does not apply either. Just `Teacher.find(5).classes` gives you the all the classes teacher 5 has, and `Teacher.find(5).classes.first.room` would give you the room for the first of these classes.

Comment: thanks janfoeh, I've fixed the typos (I adapted the example from my problem to make it easier to understand so I don't know well for the singularization :) )

Comment: I would like to return a list of {teacher_id, classe_id, room_id} for all the entries corresponding to my teacher name. Something like `Teacher.find(5).classes.all.room` (which obviously doesn't work)

Comment: So you want to make a custom hash that has these three values in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to build a list such as

```
[
 {teacher_id: 5, class_id: 9, room_id: 3},
 {teacher_id: 5, class_id: 10, room_id: 2},
 ...
]
```

for a single teacher, try

```
Teacher.find(5).classes.map do |klass|
  {
    teacher_id: klass.teacher_id,
    class_id: klass.id,
    room_id: klass.room_id
  }
end
```

(I'm using `klass` here because `class` is a reserved word in Ruby).

Answer (score 0):

you can find your answer in this page:

[RailsGuides: Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

```
Teacher.where(name: "Joe").joins(:classes).joins(:rooms)
```

Comment: Please do not just post a link, but [provide some context](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) around it instead.

Comment: This returns `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'rooms' was not found on Teacher; perhaps you misspelled it?`
And yes I've read the Rails Guide.